# Pb to load and initialize Custom Cache Store with Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite

We want to use Ignite as a cache layer on top of Postgres.
We have implemented a Custom Cache Store.
And we experiment some troubles in some situation where Ignite is not stable and we have such error :

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Client node disconnected: null at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheGateway.checkState(GridCacheGateway.java:97) at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheGateway.isStopped(GridCacheGateway.java:269) at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.checkProxyIsValid(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1597) at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.onEnter(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1621) at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.get(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:673)
```

Ignite is launched apart of our application, and when we launch our app, we loadcache and disable WAL.
When we relaunch our app, without relaunch Ignite, we have these issues.
I am wonder why. Is there any link with the fact that WAL must not be disable? And how to know that cache is already initialised and do not need to loadCache? DO you have recommendation for several apps with custom cache store, connected with one ignite cluster?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check out https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/connect-client-nodes:

> While a client is in a disconnected state and an attempt to reconnect is in progress, the Ignite API throws a `IgniteClientDisconnectedException`. The exception contains a future that represents a re-connection operation. You can use the future to wait until the operation is complete.

Also, [WAL enable-disable is known to have issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13976), and it's only safe to do on stable topology. Please share logs if you want to investigate.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we experiment strange behavior. We have 
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object only when we use a ignite cluster installed directly on our platform, when we use docker, we have no exception. How do you explain that?

Comment: Try asking another question with details.